# Cookie not showing up in request

Tags: java, spring, cookies

I'm working with Spring and have 2 controllers, one of them is:

```
@RequestMapping("/meni/{id}")
    public String meni(@PathVariable String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
 cookie = new Cookie("fake_session",id);
 cookie.setMaxAge(30*60);
 response.addCookie(cookie);
 return "meni";

}
```

Then in the 'meni' static HTML page, I have a post request that goes to:

```
@PostMapping("/index/{id}")
    public void post(@PathVariable String id,@RequestBody TestDTO testDTO, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
         Cookie [] cookies = request.getCookies();
 for (int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){
        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
        if (cookie.getName().equals("fake_session")){
             System.out.println("Same cookie!");
                }


}
```

However, the if never gets passed. If i go to the get controller twice, it recognizes the cookie, but if i go the post controller, it the if does not get passed. Everything else is running smoothly in the post controller, it does all its other tasks well.

I go to the Post controller by clicking a button that calls a ajax function in my java script that sends a POST request to that URL. Am I suppose to do something with the cookie there maybe ? I always go to the GET controller before going to the post controller so that the cookie gets created.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spring MVC's `@CookieValue(value = "fake_session", defaultValue = "default")` to access data set within any HTTP cookie in your `post` method.